# how to get localhost working on xp in parallels desktop

Tags: windows-xp, osx-lion, parallels

Im using parallels desktop on my macbook (lion os) and I want to get xampp/localhost to work on the version of XP I have installed so I am able to test my websites in Internet explorer.

Obviously I don't want to have to install two different versions of xampp on my parallels desktop as that would mean duplicating sql databases etc.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After further research I have found that if you go to Terminal and type in the command "ifconfig" and look for the "vnic1" section which is the last section to be printed and it has an ip address called "inet" e.g. "10.37.129.2" this will take you directly to local host.

If it doesn't work you must ensure that your parallels is set to a shared network under the preferences network section. Hope this helps others who are having difficulties.

Comment: still not for me. both vnic0 vnic1. and yes it is set to "shared network" also accessible ONLY inside parallels sadly. EDIT: it does works on 10.37.129.3 not 2